# count occurence of '0'-'9' in a string C++

Tags: c++, char

I'm trying to make a program that will ask the user to entrer a numbers only string.once entered the program must count the occurence of each number
and fill this in a table.
Exemple : user entrers "01230012340067080" the program should return: 7 2 2 2 1 0 1 1 1 0

occurence of 0 : 7
occurence of 1 : 2
occurence of 2 : 2
occurence of 3 : 2
occurence of 4 : 1
occurence of 5 : 0
occurence of 6 : 1
occurence of 7 : 1
occurence of 8 : 1
occurence of 9 : 0

here is my code, it does not return the desired results

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_CH = 64;


bool is_number(char chaine[MAX_CH])
{
    int l,i;
    i=0;
    l=strlen(chaine);
    for (i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if (chaine[i]<'0' || chaine[i]>'9')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


void tableau_occurence(char chaine_a_tester[MAX_CH], int taboccurence[10])
{
  //int i;
  //int j,c;
  //j=0;
  //i=0;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
      for (char j='0';j<'10';j ++)
      {
          if (chaine_a_tester[i] == j)
          {
           taboccurence[i]=taboccurence[i]+1;
          }

      }

   }
}

void tab_ini(int tableau[10])
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        tableau[i]=0;
    }
}
void affiche_tab(int tableau[10])
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<tableau[i]<<"     ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void affiche_after(int tableau[10])
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<"nombre de "<< i<<" est : "<<tableau[i]<<endl;
    }

}




int main(void)
{
    char unechaine[MAX_CH];
    int tab[10];
    tab_ini(tab);
    affiche_tab(tab);
    cout<<"entrer votre chaine numerique  "<<endl;
    cin>>unechaine;
    while (is_number(unechaine)!= 1)
    {
        cout<<"numbers only!!"<<endl;
        cin>>unechaine;
    }
    tableau_occurence(unechaine,tab);
    affiche_after(tab);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is the [std::count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) function and its variants. Why the `<string.h>` header?

Comment: @Ron . string.h cuz I used strlen. As for std:count, I'm trying to do it without using any existing functions

Comment: Pity, if you used proper string and the standard library functions the entire program could fit into 11 lines of code or less.

Comment: Yup, I know, but as I said I'm trying to write the functions, and avoid using existing functions.

Comment: `'10'` is not a character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To count the number of occurrences of each digit, convert the character to the corresponding number and use that as an index into an array. Here's a sketch:

```
int digit_counts[10];

while (*str) {
    if ('0' <= *str && *str <= '9')
        digit_counts[*str - '0']++;
    ++str;
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm! thx a lot!